# Side Menu matching full screen

Tags: html, css, height

CSS

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #000000;
    width: 15%;
}
```

Setting the height to 100% makes the menu to cover the full screen properly, but if the content in my page is more and i need to scroll down, the side menu looks awkward as its height is the same as the screen size of my computer.

I want the height of the scrollbar to take up the whole screens height even when i scroll down. How can i achieve that

Comment: Can you set position:fixed;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can try this............

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 230px;
}

.sideNavbar {
  height: 100vh;  
  width: 150px;
  background: #0004;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.sideNavbar .sidemenu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sideNavbar .sidemenu li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sideNavbar">
  <ul class="sidemenu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam nisi ad dignissimos aspernatur molestiae dhic libero pariatur assumenda sit. Soluta eveniet, quos, porro, aliquam commodi quae am assumenda iure, nesciunt aut, animi re ad eum, provident, molestias ullam accusamus ea suscipit cum!</p>
<br>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque nam necessitatibus ipsum, consequatur corporis culpa, ducimus cum dignissimos ut quae nihil domodi dolorum est. Magni amet praesentium sint voluptates odio, ullam optio quia nobis inventore recusandae laudantium quo, sit repudiandae aliquid! Consequuntur, culpa! Invens suscipit est! Cumque dolorem enim, deluta temporibus cupiditate cum.
</p>
<br>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque nam necessitatibus ipsum, consequatur corporis culpa, ducimus cum dignissimos ut quae nihil domodi dolorum est. Magni amet praesentium sint voluptates odio, ullam optio quia nobis inventore recusandae laudantium quo, sit repudiandae aliquid! Consequuntur, culpa! Invens suscipit est! Cumque dolorem enim, deluta temporibus cupiditate cum.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
height: 100%
max-height: 100%
overflow-y: scroll
```

Can you try that?